# sql relation show sum(values) for each record of ther table

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have 2 tables 1 for web-pages detail
and the other is for visits
as below

PAGES

```
pid pname      and-more-columns
1   index      -----------
2   contact    -----------
3   about      -----------
```

VISITS

```
vid   pid    ip          datetime
1      1    222.1.1.1     2013-01-01 11:11:11
2      1    12.12.2.1     2013-01-01 11:21:11 
3      3    222.1.1.1     2013-01-02 10:11:11
4      2    12.12.2.1     2013-02-01 11:21:11 
5      3    222.1.1.1     2013-03-01 11:14:11
6      1    12.12.2.1     2013-04-01 11:55:11
```

I want to display as below

```
pid pname      and-more-columns   total_visits (shud count from VISITS table)
1   index      -----------           3 
2   contact    -----------           1
3   about      -----------           2
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want "0" where there is no match, then you want a left outer join:

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(v.pid)
FROM PAGES p left outer join
     VISITS v
     ON p.pid = v.pid
GROUP BY p.pid
```

Note that this is grouping by only one field in the `group by` clause.  This uses a MySQL (mis)feature called "hidden columns".  This version also assumes that the `pages.pid` field is unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(v.pid)
FROM PAGES p
INNER JOIN VISITS v
ON p.pid = v.pid
GROUP BY p.pid, p.pname, <list all other columns here>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    v.*,
    count(p.pid) AS `TotalVisits`
FROM PAGES AS p
INNER JOIN VISITS AS v ON v.pid = p.pid
GROUP BY p.pid
```